Connection Closed BEFORE Send Operation After Upgrading Spring Boot to 3.2.4
I've recently upgraded my Spring Boot application from version 2.5 to 3.2.4. After deploying the updated application to production, I started receiving the following logs excessively:
r.n.c.AbortedException: Connection has been closed BEFORE send operation
    at r.n.c.AbortedException.beforeSend(AbortedException.java:59)
    Suppressed: r.c.p.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    *__checkpoint ⇢ Handler controllerPackage#stream(String, List, Map, ServerHttpRequest) [DispatcherHandler]
Original Stack Trace:
        at r.n.c.AbortedException.beforeSend(AbortedException.java:59)
        at r.n.h.HttpOperations.then(HttpOperations.java:171)
        at r.n.ReactorNetty$OutboundThen.<init>(ReactorNetty.java:696)
        at r.n.ReactorNetty$OutboundThen.<init>(ReactorNetty.java:689)
        at r.n.NettyOutbound.then(NettyOutbound.java:358)
        at r.n.c.ChannelOperations.send(ChannelOperations.java:283)
        at r.n.NettyOutbound.sendGroups(NettyOutbound.java:227)
        at o.s.h.s.r.ReactorServerHttpResponse.writeAndFlushWithInternal(ReactorServerHttpResponse.java:97)
        at o.s.h.s.r.AbstractServerHttpResponse.lambda$null$10(AbstractServerHttpResponse.java:247)
        at o.s.h.s.r.AbstractServerHttpResponse.doCommit(AbstractServerHttpResponse.java:297)
        ... 81 frames truncated

The application has started behaving abnormally, and I cannot figure out the root cause. Nothing in the infrastructure has changed, and I'm particularly suspicious about the reactor.netty.pool.maxConnections configuration. However, I checked, and nothing has changed there either. Do you have any suggestions?

This exception says that the server wants to send a response but the client already closed the connection.

Yes, it does. However, client side did not change anything. Also, I’ve tested on test and stage and exception never thrown.

take tcp dump so it will be more clear

Could you also share a piece of code? I had similar issue when upgrading from a minor version of Spring Boot (forgot which one around 3.2.X), it was due to the fact that I was reading only a single chunk of a chunked response.
